# String repetition operator doesn't commute

Tags: scala

This works.

```
print("scala" * 5)
```

This doesn't.

```
print(5 * "scala")
```

Why not have both work? Doesn't it make sense for the `*` operator to commute?

Edit: To clarify, I was wondering if there was a compelling reason why the language doesn't have `5 * "scala"` as a method on Int.

Comment: There is no operator(in sense of other programming language, like C/C++) in scala, everything is method or object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine that Scala doesn't have `5 * "scala"` as a method on Int because one can easily be added.

```
package com.example{
    class RichInt2(val num: Int) {
        def *(str: String): String = {
            str * num
        }
    }

    object RichInt2 {
        implicit def intToRichInt2(n: Int) = new RichInt2(n)
    }
}

import com.example.RichInt2._

object Run extends App {
    print(5 * "scala")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`*` is method on objects in scala:

`"Scala" * 5` is same as calling `*` method of string object.

`5 * "Scala"` means calling `*` method of integer object.

Answer (score 1):

`print("scala" * 5)` evaluates to `print("scala".*(5))`.

That is, Strings have an operator `*` that takes an integer parameter to repeat the string.

To make `5 * "scala"` do the same as `"scala" * 5`, you would need an operator defined for integers like this:

```
def * (s: String) = s * x   // where x is the integer
```

In Scala `Int` doesn't have such operator, and that seems to make sense.

You could play with this, for example:

```
class MyInt(x: Int) {
  def * (s: String) = s * x
}

val a = new MyInt(5)
println(a * "scala")                 //> scalascalascalascalascala
```